# java.sql.SQLException: Protocol violation

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc, oracle11g, ojdbc

Iam very new to oracle DB, iam facing an issue regarding protocol violation when my app is under UAT.

We use oracle 11g database, ojdbc5.jar, linux platform, JDK 1.7.

please find the error log below :

```
2014-10-29 21:45:51,843 -  INFO - [Thread-72] - (StigRunner.java54) -  Starting (JobId:1618) at 2014-10-29T21:45:51.424+05:30
2014-10-29 21:45:57,686 - ERROR - [Thread-72] - (StigRunner.java68) - se.signa.stig.stig.common.StigException: select * from job_type where jbt_id = 10 se.signa.stig.stig.common.StigException: select * from job_type where jbt_id = 10 java.sql.SQLException: Protocol violation: [6, 7, 3]
2014-10-29 21:45:57,686 -  INFO - [Thread-72] - (StigRunner.java69) - Failed (JobId:1618) at 2014-10-29T21:45:57.686+05:30
```

Can any one suggest how to resolve this, we tried using ojdbc6 and ojdbc7 jars, tried changing xms and xmx values also but no use.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you run any queries? Is the user you're connected to Oracle as in a normal valid state - if you connect as them through SQL*Plus do you get any warnings, e.g. about password expiration?

Comment: no password expiration issue.... this issue is found only while doing UAT